# how to get RadEditor user text in Jquery

Tags: jquery, radeditor

This is what i did

```
 var varPrimayNotes = $("input[id*=txtDescription]").val();
```

Here in varPrimaryNotes an getting

```
{"enabled":true,"emptyMessage":"","validationText":"","valueAsString":""}
```

How can i get exact text of RadEditor Telerik using Jquery.

This is my radeditor control

```
<rad:RadEditor ID="txtDescription" runat="server" width="800px"
            Height="150px" Skin="Vista">
            <tools>
                <rad:EditorToolGroup Tag="MainToolbar">
                    <rad:EditorTool Name="FindAndReplace" />
                    <rad:EditorSeparator />
                    <rad:EditorSplitButton Name="Undo">
                    </rad:EditorSplitButton>
                    <rad:EditorSplitButton Name="Redo">
                    </rad:EditorSplitButton>
                    <rad:EditorSeparator />
                    <rad:EditorTool Name="Cut" />
                    <rad:EditorTool Name="Copy" />
                    <rad:EditorTool Name="Paste" ShortCut="CTRL+V" />
                    <rad:EditorTool Name="Ajax spellcheck" />
                </rad:EditorToolGroup>
                    <rad:EditorToolGroup Tag="Formatting">
                        <rad:EditorTool Name="Bold" />
                        <rad:EditorTool Name="Italic" />
                        <rad:EditorTool Name="Underline" />
                        <rad:EditorSeparator />
                        <rad:EditorSplitButton Name="ForeColor">
                        </rad:EditorSplitButton>
                        <rad:EditorSplitButton Name="BackColor">
                        </rad:EditorSplitButton>
                        <rad:EditorSeparator />
                        <rad:EditorDropDown Name="FontName">
                        </rad:EditorDropDown>
                        <rad:EditorDropDown Name="RealFontSize">
                        </rad:EditorDropDown>
                    </rad:EditorToolGroup>
                </tools>
            <content>

            </content>
        </rad:RadEditor>
```

Youe Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content area of RadEditor is not an input but an editable iframe, so you should get reference to the iframe and obtain its content.

Another approach is to use the Telerik Static Library to get reference to the control and its HTML content:

```
$telerik.findEditor("txtDescription").get_html(true);
```

You can find more information at: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/telerik-static-client-library.html

Best regards, Rumen

Answer (score 1):

The content area of RadEditor is not an input but an editable iframe, so you should get reference to the iframe and obtain its content.

Another approach is to use the Telerik Static Library to get reference to the control and its HTML content:

```
$telerik.findEditor("txtDescription").get_html(true);
```

You can find more information at:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/telerik-static-client-library.html

Best regards,
Rumen